# Python's print command only solves the first math problem out of multiple. print(a+50, a/2)=50, 0.0

Tags: python

```py
a=0.0
b=0.0
c=0.0
d=0.0
a1=0.0
b1=0.0
c1=0.0
d1=0.0
z=0.0

print(50/2)
print(a+50.0, a/2.0)
```

the `print(50/2)` works, it gives 25. but the `print(a+50, a/2)` gives `50, 0.0`
Why isn't it saying `50, 25`?

Comment: You set `a = 0.0` and then later print `a/2.0`. It seems it is right to print `0.0`

Comment: Because the value of a is 0 and `0/2 = 0`... This is what should happen. Why do you expect 25?

Comment: `print` is not an interactive console, I'm not sure if you expected this to work like `a += 50`

Comment: @Cireo Yeah I did expect it to work like that, I have no idea why I thought that though lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `a = 0.0`, and `0.0 / 2 = 0` The `print a+50` won't actually change the value of `a`.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind I feel like an idiot. I needed to put a=+50 above it lol.
Just in case somebody is somehow making this mistake as well I will explain:

It gave me 50, 0 because I asked it to give me the answer to a+50 but I did not make it change a into 50. So when I went to divide a by 2, it couldn't because a was still 0.

Comment: Did you mean to say `a += 50`?